# How can I get the equivalent of Meteor.userId if I don't use an accounts package?

Tags: meteor

If I don't use the `accounts-ui` package, `Meteor.userId()` is null.

How can I get the equivalent of `Meteor.userId()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Meteor.userId()` is supplied by the accounts package itself.

Just as the name implies, the accounts packages provide you a base, authentication managers and user interface components to manage your Meteor application's user-bound requirements.

So you either have to use at least accounts-base, or if you don't you need to implement your own solution to get a reference to a user object (that you create).

Comment: Thank your answer.How do reference to a user object(that my create)?  You can give me the code example ?

Comment: Creating an accounts package from scratch is not a trivial task. That's why there is one in Meteor core. But if you want, you can take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780379/impletmenting-a-custom-meteor-accounts-package and this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/0.7.0.1/packages/accounts-base for inspiration